# Search Console says my horizontal website is a problem on mobile phones

Tags: css, seo

I made an horizontal website which works well in all browsers and devices. But Google Search Console says that the content should not be larger than the screen on mobile phones. Does anyone know how to solve the problem in the Console without changing the page design ?

My page width in written in "vw". Actually it's 600vw because there are 6 horizontal sections of 100vw each.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is about SEO, not programming](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618). General SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am curious to see what other answers you will get here! I am not a specialist, but wanted to contribute here with the things I think about it. I spent a lot of time in the past with the Google Mobile-Friendly validator tools and I know that can be frustrated sometimes.

In general, horizontal scroll on mobile is discouraged by most people, including Google (see [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/#size_content_to_the_viewport), for example). However, the "swipe" gesture is used a lot in Mobile Apps and even some websites. It is interesting to see that even the google search page on mobile, has some content in a horizontal scroll:

[image]

I am not sure how the Google Console check the webpage, but I believe that having some content in a horizontal scroll is not the problem. But you need to follow some conventions and best practices. The Google Material conventions has some of those intructions in the [Gestures](https://material.io/design/interaction/gestures.html#types-of-gestures) section. There is also a really good article about it [here](https://uxdesign.cc/best-practices-for-horizontal-lists-in-mobile-21480b9b73e5).

In summary, I feel like having the whole website in a horizontal scroll, doesn't feel natural for the mobile experience. Having lists, catalogs and other components like that; could be acceptable, but not the whole page.

In case of games or video apps, the horizontal experience is the indicated one, but in those cases, the user will actually rotate the device to use it horizontally.

I would suggest to either:

- Consider updating the design to use swipe components that will make sense, not the whole page
- Consider creating a mobile app

Hope this helps in someway :)

Comment: Thank for you answer, I will read the articles. Yes it helps. I was surprised about Google Console's problem because this is the first time I really use it. If I understand well, I should adapt to Google's requirement and maybe try to make something just for mobile. Maybe I'll make a vertical design for mobile and horizontal one for bigger screen.

Comment: Finally I made a vertical version of my website for mobile and now Google likes it very much !